# CSS z-index and mobile devices

Tags: css, overlay

I have a jquery modal dialog box where I want to put an entire shadow just between that modal dialog box and the screen so I created an overlay with a `<div>`:

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay btn-hidden"></div>
<div id="myDialogBox" name="myDialogBox" class="myDialogBox"></div>
```

and in CSS I settled as:

```
.myDialogBox {
    z-index: 999 !important;
}

.overlay {
    z-index: 800 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

so on desktop screen I figure the overlay is applied correctly right behind the dialog box.... but when on Chrome I debug switching from desktop to mobile screens I see the overlay goes on top so I can't act on the dialog box.... I tried also to put `position: relative` for the overlay when I am on mobile using `@media screen and (max-width: 769px)` but on mobile the overlay doesn't even appear... so is there a way to force the overlay to stay right behind the modal dialog box also on mobile screen?....

Comment: Have you tried using the native `<dialog>` element?

Comment: @cloned , yes but since I load content from another .php file in the <div> I use as a modal dialog box I had too much work to change and manage because <dialog> has different behavior than <div> and jquery's dialog....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided to keep that `@media screen and (min-width: 769px)` to activate the overlay only when I am on desktop screen because on mobile devices it looks like the dialog window covers already like 95% of the screen so not really need for overlay... thanks anyway to all!!! Cheers! :-)